# How to install INTL into Php 5.5.9 using PHPBREW

Tags: php, pecl, intl, phpbrew

I'm working on some legacy code using PHP 5.5.9.

Which uses intl.

I installed php 5.5.9 with PhpBrew on my mac machine running:

```
phpbrew install  --mirror=https://www.php.net  php-5.5.9 +default +mysql +pdo +openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl +bz2=/usr/local/opt/bzip2 +curl=/usr/local/opt/curl +zlib=/usr/local/opt/zlib
```

Now i successfully have a working php 5.5.9 on my machine.

When i try to install INTL using:

```
sudo ./pecl install intl
```

And give path for icu4c version 58.1. It installs.

PHP info says:

[image]

But when i:

```
<?php
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('NL_nl', null, null);
var_dump($formatter);
phpinfo();
exit;
```

It always returns `NULL`.

How is this possible?

THanks in advance.

Comment: PHP version 5.5 is past end-of-life since 2016. Does it still make sense to make it work? It is broken now and won't become less broken with age...

Comment: What web server do you use? If you use FPM or Apache bear in mind that you have to reset it after the installation from PECL :) There are also other alternatives - you can install already working Docker container! This will solve all your issues :)

Comment: I used docker to solve this.